# jqGrid header becomes big when using float in css

Tags: css, jqgrid, css-float

I had a jqGrid displaying perfectly ok.

Then I started to develop a basic site layout structure and got into problem: jqGrid's header got really huge! :)

Here's the [screenshot](http://www.dpimka.org/files/images/jqgrid1.jpg).

The structure of the page:

```
<div id="sidebar1" />
<div id="sidebar2" />
<div id="centralpart">
    <div id="jqgrid">....</div>
</div>
```

And css:

```
#sidebar1 {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

#sidebar2 {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

#centralpart {
  margin: 0 300px 0 150px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I detected that things broke because of floats: once I remove them jqGrid's header goes back to normal size (although other parts of layout get messed up ;))

Also I noticed that with floats header spans down exactly by amount of height of the right sidebar, so it looks like it tries to float it...

I also tried to clear floats by putting *<br style="clear:both" />* before jgGrid, but that shifted it to the bottom of the page beyond sidebars, that's not what I want.

I'm only taking my first steps to css/html/jqgrid, so I can miss something really obvious :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all it seems to me you have to fix `margin` value of `#centralpart` to the following

```
#centralpart {
    margin: 0px 320px 0px 170px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:red
}
```

To solve your main problem you should set `height` of the titelbar div `div.ui-jqgrid-titlebar` explicitly:

```
div.ui-jqgrid-titlebar {
    height: 16px;
}
```

Like you can see on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/gridFloat.htm) the results will be much better after the changes. (I included `background-color` in every div to see more clear the size of every div.

Comment: Great! That works! Although I had to make header somewhat bigger. I'm curious - what was the reason? What did I do wrong? Why my floats broke jqGrid? Also, whats the point in increasing margin? :)

Comment: @dpimka: The question with margins will be clear if you just include `background-color` in every div: see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/gridFloat0.htm). The problem with `div.ui-jqgrid-titlebar` is mostly jqGrid problem. I am sure that there are more fixes of the same problem, but `div.ui-jqgrid-titlebar {height:16px}` seems me easy enough.

Comment: Haha, I get it now! Thank you very much :) Very informative and greatly visualized. I appreciate it! :)

Comment: @Oleg On your demo if you pull the right side of your window in, you can see the red square disappear and then when the pink hits the jQGrid the title messes up and becomes higher. Is this unintentional? Is there a way to keep the titlebar from expanding on collision with that right div?