# JQGrid caption inserting gigantic header

Tags: jqgrid

I want to add a header to my JQgrid without pushing a custom div right above my grid.  I found the caption option which appears to create a header that looks good.  However, right below the header another div appears which is ~4x the height of the header.  This looks to simply be a div that allows a user to hide or unhide the entire grid.

Question 1:  Is this hide/unhide supposed to be this big?  My height and width are both set to auto for the grid.

Question 2:  Is there a way to easily remove this hide/unhide area?

If you think you need source code or an image to show the problem let me know and I'll post it.  It needs to be scrubbed of company data first, hence me not putting it in the initial post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the same issue as [Large header in jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669138/large-header-in-jqgrid)?

Both answers include workarounds to get rid of the huge header.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that.  Thanks!

Comment: Yep.  Couldn't accept until 5 or 10 minutes after initial post :P

Comment: I want to add that explicit setting of the height of the `div.ui-jqgrid-titlebar` already solve the problem: see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/gridFloat.htm) from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8057675/315935). To remove this hide/unhide area in the title bar one can use `hidegrid: false` option of the jqGrid.